# $\varphi \in Aut(G)$ such that $\varphi(g)g^{-1} \in Z(G) \; \forall g \in G$, prove that $\varphi(x) = x \;\forall x\in G'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $\varphi \in Aut(G)$ such that $\varphi(g)g^{-1} \in Z(G) \quad \forall g \in G$

prove that $\varphi(x) = x \quad \forall x\in G'$

I have tried to use the fact that $\forall g\in G \quad g \varphi(g)g^{-1} = \varphi(g)$

and then try to calculate $\varphi(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)$
but couldn't get a result

edit : $Z(g)$ is the center of $G$, and $G' = < [x,y] | x,y\in G>$

Comment: what is $Z(G)$ ? (and $G'$ ?)

Comment: From the given  condition $\phi(g)=c_gg$ where $c_g$ is in $Z(G)$. Also note that $\phi(g)^{-1}=\phi(g^{-1})=c_g^{-1}g^{-1}$. Using this calculate $\phi(a^{-1}b^{-1}ab)$.

Comment: @user1952009: Z(G) is the center of $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to show that, for any $x,y\in G$, you have
$$
\varphi(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy
$$
since $G'$ is generated by the commutators. This is the same as proving that
$$
\varphi(x)^{-1}\varphi(y)^{-1}\varphi(x)\varphi(y)=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy
$$
or, rearranging terms,
$$
\varphi(x)\varphi(y)y^{-1}x^{-1}=\varphi(y)\varphi(x)x^{-1}y^{-1}
$$
Now, by hypothesis, $\varphi(y)y^{-1}\in Z(G)$, so the left-hand side can be rewritten as
$$
\varphi(y)y^{-1}\varphi(x)x^{-1}
$$
We can rewrite the right-hand side in the same way, because $\varphi(x)x^{-1}\in Z(G)$.